# D compiler DMD doesn't link object files

Tags: macos, compiler-construction, linker, d, dmd

i have a source file for d named "dprogram.d" and use the command $ dmd dprogram.d in the terminal on mac osx to create an executable. according to the official documentation the compiler will automatically compile the source and link the .o object files (http://dlang.org/dmd-linux.html#linking) but it doesn't seem to do so.

the compiler will create a .o file but not an executable and the only feedback i get from the terminal is a message: "gcc: no such file or directory" as if the gcc tries to link the object file but cant find it.

what is the correct way to compile a .d source with the dmd (digital mars D) compiler on mac osx?

(edit: on windows it does work, it autmatically creates the .exe but on mac osx it doesnt)

Comment: Just install GCC and that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like gcc is either not properly installed or is missing from you PATH. dmd uses gcc to do the linking underneath the hood, so if it's not there, then linking won't work. If you fix that, then dmd should do the linking as part of the build.